# How notification works for mobile app

Tags: getstream-io

My mobile app is using api created in larval to get stream data.

How to handle notification when some one like my post or commented on my post.

is there some pull/push notification is there in get-stream to handle this?

Comment: http://getstream.io/docs/#realtime

Comment: and: http://getstream.io/docs/#realtime-webhooks and: http://getstream.io/docs/#realtime-sqs

Comment: @Matthisk how to work with webhook. do I need to setup this or its getstream.io which setup this. Is this available in free version ?